# Retorno de dados em form inputs

Tags: php

> Olá! Eu tenho alguns clientes cadastrados no banco de dados, a escolha do cliente é feita através de um form select que me retornam os dados em outro form select. Gostaria de devolver os dados em form tipo input diferentes e separados. Tipo endereço em um input, bairro em outro e assim sucessivamente. Alguém poderia me direcionar como faço?

```
<?php
    require_once ("DBController.php");
    $db_handle = new DBController();
    $query = "SELECT * FROM clientes";
    $clienteResult = $db_handle->runQuery($query);
    ?>
    <html>
    <head>
    <TITLE>Retornar dados nos input</TITLE>


    <head>
    <style>
    body {
        width: 610px;
        font-family: calibri;
    }

    .form-DronpDown {
        border: 1px solid #7ddaff;
        background-color: #C8EEFD;
        margin: 2px 0px;
        padding: 40px;
        border-radius: 4px;
    }

    .form-control {
        padding: 10px;
        border: #bdbdbd 1px solid;
        border-radius: 4px;
        background-color: #FFF;
        width: 50%;
    }

    .row {
        padding-bottom: 15px;
    }
    </style>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script>
    function getdados() {
            var str='';
            var val=document.getElementById('cliente-list');
            for (i=0;i< val.length;i++) { 
                if(val[i].selected){
                    str += val[i].value + ','; 
                }
            }         
            var str=str.slice(0,str.length -1);

        $.ajax({          
                type: "GET",
                url: "get_dados.php",
                data:'clienteID='+str,
                success: function(data){
                    $("#dados-list").html(data);
                }
        });
    }
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="form-DronpDown">
    <div class="row">

    <label>cliente:</label><br /> 
    <select name="cliente[]"  id="cliente-list" class="form-control" onChange="getdados();" >
    <option value="">Select cliente</option>

    <?php
    foreach ($clienteResult as $cliente) {
        ?>
    <option value="<?php echo $cliente["id"]; ?>"><?php echo $cliente["cliente_name"]; ?></option>
    <?php
    }
    ?>

    </select>
    </div>

            <div class="row">
                <label>Dados:</label><br /> 
                <div name="dados[]"  id="dados-list" class="form-control"  size=5></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Se os dados que você diz é na função do javascript, você consegue jogar os dados em qualquer lugar.

Por exemplo:

```
...
success: function(data){
     document.querySelector('#endereco').value = data.endereco
     document.querySelector('#cidade').value = data.cidade
}
```

E no html conter os inputs

```
<input id="endereco">
<input id="cidade">
```